# Inject not working in dagger-hilt and error whit this error lateinit property repository has not been initialized

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-viewmodel, dagger-hilt

I use dagger-hilt version 2.48
This is my appModule class:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideDatabase(@ApplicationContext context: Context) =
    Room.databaseBuilder(context, V2BasketDatabase::class.java, "basket_database")
        .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
        .allowMainThreadQueries()
        .build()

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideContext(@ApplicationContext appContext: Context): Context {
    return appContext
}

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideBasketDao(db: V2BasketDatabase) = db.basketDao()


}
```

And this is my viewModel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class V2CoffeeShopMenuFragmentViewModel @Inject constructor(application: Application) 
: BaseViewModel(application) {

private lateinit var readAllData: LiveData<List<V2ModelBasket>>

@Inject
lateinit var repository: V2BasketRepository

fun initDb(context: Context) {
    readAllData = repository.readAllData
}

fun readProductByProductId(productId: Int): V2ModelBasket? {
    return if (repository.readProductByProductId(productId) != null)
        repository.readProductByProductId(productId)
    else null
}

}
```

And I use my viewModel in my fragment like this

```
private val viewModel: V2CoffeeShopMenuFragmentViewModel by viewModels()
```

But when I call my viewModel, it crash and the log is this:

> kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property repository has not been initialized

How should I correct this error?

Comment: Your repository type is `V2BasketRepository` but your module doesn't have any method with return type of it. Did you constract inject repository?

Comment: Could you show your Repository class? The repository needs an @Inject constructor, and if it is implementing an interface, it should be bind it in your module